# remove open_basedir restriction

Tags: .htaccess, open-basedir

I am running a script and i am getting the following error:

```
WARNING: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/php/Am/View/Helper/HeadScript.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/1205915141/members-net/:/tmp:/usr/share/pear/) in line 198 of file /home/1205915141/members-net/public_html/library/Zend/Loader.php
```

I asked my host to remove the restriction but they said they wont because of security reasons. So resolved to do it my self by overriding the php.ini with an htaccess like this:

```
php_value open_basedir  /usr/share/php/
```

but it wont work. Im not sure what is exactly the problem, whether the syntax or the path. Could you please give me a hand?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What PHP version do you use - maybe < PHP 5.3?

See http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

For PHP < 5.3 this value was PHP_INI_SYSTEM, which means it can only be set from within php.ini or httpd.conf. Starting with PHP 5.3 its value is PHP_INI_ALL, so you can set it from within a htaccess file.